# Boot problems after uninstalling Ubuntu

Tags: boot, uefi, vaio, sony, secure-boot

I have a Sony Vaio PC and after uninstalling Ubuntu from my laptop I went into a problem that I can't fix. I get a error message that says:

```
SECURE BOOT FAILED! Your VAIO has detected an invalid operating system.
```

I have tried to make a recovery and the only thing I get as a result is the following error message that is displayed in white text on a black background, and then I get into the same VAIO CARE section saying the same thing again! This appears before it enters the VAIO care system:

```
Could not open "\EFI\BOOT\fallback.efi": 14
Failed to open "\EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi" - 800000000000000E
Failed to load Image
Failed to open "\EFI\BOOT\MokManager.efi" - 800000000000000E 
Failed to load Image
```

I don't know what to do. Please help me. I am studying and therefore I have to use my laptop every day!

Comment: Are you running a dual boot? If so, what with? It would also be useful to know how you uninstalled Ubuntu.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in your firmware's setup utility. Ignore most of House Zet's answer unless you have problems after that point.

Comment: I deleted the Ubuntu partition and I was running Ubuntu and Windows 8.1 in a dual boot!

But when I turn off Secure Boot it will boot into GNU GRUB Version 2.00-19ubuntu2.1!

Have to try to write exit but it keeps restarting and getting back to GNU GRUB!

Answer (score 2):

This message appears just because you enabled secure boot but use an unrolled boot manager.

1. Disable secure boot in your uefi setting.
2. Log into windows. And press **win+s**.
3. Enter **cmd** then select run as admin.
4. In the commandline, input the following things:

   ```
   mountvol S: /S 
   bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi
   ```

Warning: If you've made any changes to \EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi, this will not work as expected. You may need to register

```
\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgr.efi
```

instead of

```
\EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi
```

But I haven't tested it, **do it at your own risk**.

Finally, Reboot, enable secure boot.

Alternatively, you can also install the boot manager **reFind** to manage all your efi. Take a look at here:

http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

If you would like to install more os in future, this boot manager will help greatly.

---

**Update:**

In the screnn shot, I found that you may delete the EFI partition. This is a really bad suitation but still can be fixed with some effort. 
You have to recover it manually. Follow these steps:

**Warning: all the disks like /dev/sdax in command is just an example, you should replace them according to your system environment.**

1. Make a bootable usb system, such as ubuntu live image. Make sure you have disabled secure boot.
2. Boot into this live system. and run **lsblk**, you will get something like the following output, but without efi mounted:

   ```
   $ lsblk
   NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
   sda       8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
   ├─sda1    8:1    0   260M  0 part 
   ├─sda2    8:2    0   1.5G  0 part 
   ├─sda3    8:3    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
   ├─sda4    8:4    0   128M  0 part 
   ├─sda5    8:5    0 845.1G  0 part /home/win
   ├─sda6    8:6    0   392M  0 part 
   ├─sda7    8:7    0  33.9G  0 part 
   ├─sda8    8:8    0   500M  0 part /boot
   ├─sda9    8:9    0  19.5G  0 part /
   ├─sda11   8:11   0    27G  0 part /home
   └─sda12   8:12   0     3G  0 part [SWAP]
   ```
3. Find your Recovery Disk. For sony vaio, it is usually Windows Recovery disk /dev/sda2 with size of 1.5GB (or EFI recovery disk /dev/sda1 with size 260MB).
4. Mount this disk with

   ```
   mkdir recovery && mount /dev/sda2 recovery
   ```
5. Make sure you get bootmgr.efi in this disk. Usually you can find it under **./recovery/EFI/Boot** or **./recovery/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/**.
6. Find out your original efi partition. Usually it is /dev/sda3 on sony vaio and the size of disk is **260MB**. If nothing appears to be efi partition, just make a new efi partition by yourself. Don't worry, it should be safe even you create multiply efi partitions.
7. Use

   ```
   cgdisk /dev/sda
   ```

   and make /dev/sda3 a EFI partition(set code as **ef00**). Do Not Change Any Other Thing.
8. Mount it.

   ```
   mkdir /boot/efi && mount /dev/sda3 /boot/efi
   ```
9. Copy everything under ./recover/EFI to your new efi partition.

   ```
    cp -r ./recover/EFI /boot/efi/
   ```

   Make sure the output of

   ```
   $ ls /boot/efi/EFI/
   ```

   is

   ```
   Boot/       Microsoft/
   ```
10. Make your new efi bootmanager loadable.

    ```
    efibootmgr -c -l \\EFI\\Boot\\bootx64.efi -L Microsoft
    ```

    Similar to my old answer, if the above command do not work, you may need to set windows bootloader under Microsoft\Boot:

    ```
    efibootmgr -c -l \\EFI\\Microsoft\\Boot\\bootmgr.efi -L Microsoft
    ```
11. Remove all the mounted disk and usb stick. Reboot and enable secure boot. Now you can enter your windows.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the Ubuntu partition and I was running Ubuntu and Windows 8.1 in a dual boot!

But when I turn off Secure Boot it will boot into GNU GRUB Version 2.00-19ubuntu2.1!

Have to try to write exit but it keeps restarting and getting back to GNU GRUB!