# Cant install ubuntu 12.04, 14.04 64bit on my lenovo s205

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, grub2, uefi

I've read a lot of similar topics, but nothing helped. Check out my little sad story:

1. I made a bootable USB with UNetbootin. I tried Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04, Linux Mint 17.1, Fedora KDE, Zorin.
2. Before upgrading the BIOS, which is actually UEFI (absolutely no settings except boot sequence), I got a quick message:

   ```
   Boot in secure mode
   ```

   After upgrading BIOS I see this quick message:

   ```
   \EFI\BOOT\fallback.efi": 14
   ```

   and GRUB starts after that.
3. GRUB didn't see my  Windows 7, but I thought it's OK.
4. Installation goes fine and at the end it asks to reboot. I press 'ok do it', but after rebooting I see that message (point 2) again. GRUB starts and doesn't see my fresh Ubuntu.
5. I tried to make an EFI first partition manually while installing and before it with Gparted (I DID IT A LOT OF TIMES), but nothing helped.

Comment: did you run `sudo update-grub`? Before start, read the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) on dual-booting if you're doing this for the first time.

Comment: i did while 'try ubuntu before install', 
i dont want to dual boot, i want single ubuntu

Comment: ok then if you want only Ubuntu your partition table should look like this for example https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

Comment: just tried to make BIOS-boot partition instead of EFI, same issue, "\EFI\BOOT\fallback.efi": 14" and grub doesnt see my fresh ubuntu

Comment: it clearly says how/when to set up EFI or BIOS boot as it stated it depends on your BIOS set up and disk table if it's GPT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a live USB for Ubuntu 64-bit (e.g. with UNetBootin).
2. While on the live USB installation, select *Do Something Else* and make `/dev/sda1` an "EFI" partition with size 150MB. It must be a minimum of 100MB, recommended 200MB.
3. Partition the rest of the drive however you want (`/` and `swap`, `/` and `/home` and `swap`, whatever). Use primary partitions only (you might be able to get away with an extended partition for `/home`, but I haven't tried it). This is my setup:

   - `/dev/sda1` 150MB EFI
   - `/dev/sda2` 20GB ext4 `/`
   - `/dev/sda3` 5GB swap
   - `/dev/sda4` 50GB ext4 `/home`
   - Set the boot installer to install to `/dev/sda1` (or your EFI partition #). Do not use `/dev/sda`.
4. Install.
5. Pray.
6. Awesome, now Ubuntu is installed.
7. Restart your laptop, and boot back into the live USB.
8. Now, mount your EFI partition somewhere, like this:

   ```
   mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
   ```
9. Change directories into the `EFI` directory in the mounted folder:

   ```
   cd /mnt/EFI
   ```
10. Copy over the super secret important EFI files:

    ```
    cp -rfv ubuntu boot
    ```
11. `cd` into the boot directory:

    ```
    cd boot
    ```
12. Finally, move `grubx64.efi` to `bootx64.efi`:

    ```
    mv grubx64.efi bootx64.efi
    ```
13. Restart, and you should finally have a working Ubuntu/Xubuntu 14.04 on your dumbass Lenovo S205 computer! Yay!

To get Wi-Fi working, change the boot order in BIOS to boot from network first.

Comment: IT WORKED
oh thank you good man, live long life, do a lot of good things

Answer (score 1):

After two weeks of heavy googling and checking many procedures, I came up with another solution. The Ideapad S205s issue is due to a not fully standard BIOS that supports UEFI installation, which is not compatible with the Ubuntu EFI installation process. GRUB does not get properly installed in no way. Fixing this problem was impossible for me. My solution is creating a little bit modified installation medium. In my case a USB flash.

1. Create a standard install USB with Rufus. In used Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS.
2. Open the USB and rename the `EFI` folder to another name. In used `EFInova`, but the new name is not critical.
3. Making a copy of `grubx64.efi` from `/EFInova` to the `/boot/grub` folder and another copy to the `/boot/grub/x86_64-efi` folder.
4. These two changes force booting the Ubuntu 20.04 USB in legacy BIOS mode and also installing in legacy BIOS mode which works fine for Ideapad S205 (approved with Ubuntu 16.04).
5. After booting Ubuntu 20.04 from the USB, in *Try* mode prepare your HDD with Gparted in this way:

   - First partition as ext4, with mount point `/`.
   - Second partition as `swap`.

This worked fine for me.

Comment: This worked for me when I tried installing Lubuntu 22.04 on a Lenovo Ideapad S205.
(Except step #5, I didn't mess with the partitioning, I chose the "erase everything" option during the installation process and it worked out fine - it finally didn't create an EFI partition)