# failed to open \EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I installed ubuntu 15.04 next to windows 8.1, both in UEFI mode and after that windows always booted first, so i used boot-repair to fix the grub and now i get this when the computer starts:

```
Booting in insecure mode
Failed to open \EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi - 800000000000000E
Failed to load image
Failed to open \EFI\Boot\MokManager.efi - 800000000000000E
Failed to load image
```

I can boot into windows or ubuntu but always through UEFI menu. Here is the log of boot-repair:

[boot-repair-log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11926032/)

It would be great if anyone could show me how to fix this.

My computer is a HP Pro 440 G1

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to install Ubuntu 14 LTS (64bit) on Lenovo Ideapad S205](http://askubuntu.com/questions/603478/unable-to-install-ubuntu-14-lts-64bit-on-lenovo-ideapad-s205)